# Execute a function on the end of asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-toast

i've got a little problem at the moment:
I am trying to make visible 2 buttons on my fragment after the asynktask i called is finished. For that i was using this:

```
while (!recordi.getterminé){

    } 
    terminé();
```

But this is not optimal and my app is not responding :(
So is there any solutions to call the function terminé() in the onPostExecute function?
Thanks.

Here is my code:

the fragment:

```
public class FragmentEnregistrer extends Fragment {

    String path,nomfinal, ip="http://MYIP/php";
    ImageButton mrecord,mupload,mlire;
    TextView Nomm;
    ProgressBar progressbar;
    int i=2;
    EnregistrerSon recordi;
    String id;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.enregistrer, container, false);

        mrecord= (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(record);
        mupload= (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(upload);
        mlire= (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(lire);
        Nomm = (TextView) myView.findViewById(NomWhizz);
        progressbar = (ProgressBar) myView.findViewById(progressBar);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        id=((MainActivity)getActivity()).getIdentifiant();

        mrecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Enregistrement en cours", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String nomm = Nomm.getText().toString();
                nomm=nomm.replace(" ", "_");
                nomm=nomm.replace("&", "");

                final String finalNomm = nomm;
                recordi = new EnregistrerSon();
                recordi.execute(finalNomm);
                terminé();






            }
        });

        mupload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UploadOnServer upload = new UploadOnServer();
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                upload.execute(path,nomfinal);
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                HttpGetRequest request = new HttpGetRequest();
                request.execute(ip+"/son/creation_son.php?nom_whiz="+nomfinal+"&id_createur="+id);

            }
        });

        mlire.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LireSonLocal local = new LireSonLocal();
                Uri myUri = Uri.parse("file://"+recordi.getAccess());
                local.execute(myUri);

            }
        });

        return myView;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public void terminé(){
        Log.i("Enregistrement","terminé");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Enregistrement terminé", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        path = recordi.getAccess();
        nomfinal = recordi.getNomSansExtenssions();
        Log.i("nomfinale",nomfinal);
        mlire.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mupload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.i("test","");
}

}
```

And the asynktask :

```
class EnregistrerSon extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    private Boolean isRecording = false;
    private Boolean termine = false;
    private String Nom, NOM;



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        NOM = params[0];
        if(!isRecording){
            //configuration
            Looper.prepare();
            MediaRecorder mr = new MediaRecorder();
            mr.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
            mr.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mr.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
            mr.setAudioChannels(1);
            mr.setAudioEncodingBitRate(1280000);
            mr.setAudioSamplingRate(9500000);
            mr.setOutputFile(getAccess());
            try {mr.prepare();}
            catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

            //Demarage du record
            long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis(); //pendant 15 secondes
            long wait_time = 15000;
            long end_time = start_time + wait_time;
            mr.start();
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end_time){
                Long temps = end_time - System.currentTimeMillis();

                isRecording = true;
                //pendant 15 secondes
            }
            mr.stop();
            mr.reset();
            mr.release();
            isRecording = false;
            termine = true;
            //fin de l'enregistrement
        }
        return "lol";
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);


    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    String getAccess(){
        MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
        if(Objects.equals(NOM, "Nom") || Objects.equals(NOM, "") || NOM == null ) {
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            Nom = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + "_" + now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "_" + now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "_" + now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        }
        else{
            Nom = NOM;
        }
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Whizz/");
        directory.mkdirs();
        String filename = directory +"/"+Nom+".mp3";
        Log.i("filename",filename);
        return filename;
    }

    Boolean getTerminé(){
        return termine;
    }

    String getNomSansExtenssions(){
        return Nom;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute your method `terminé` inside the `AsyncTask` class. I suggest to have the following:

1. Create an instance field of `FragmentEnregistrer` inside your `EnregistrerSon` class.

   ```
   private FragmentEnregistrer fragmentEnregistrer;
   ```
2. Create a constructor in your `EnregistrerSon` class with an expected argument of `FragmentEnregistrer` class, and assign the argument to the field variable.

   ```
   public EnregistrerSon(FragmentEnregistrer fe) {
    this.fragmentEnregistrer = fe;
   }
   ```
3. You can then call the `terminé` method in the `onPostExecute` method, as follows:

   ```
   protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
     super.onPostExecute(s);
     this.fragmentEnregistrer.terminé();
   }
   ```
4. Last, pass the instance of the `FragmentEnregistrer` object on `EnregistrerSon` instantiation.

   ```
   recordi = new EnregistrerSon(FragmentEnregistrer.this);
   recordi.execute(finalNomm);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

First, line `while (!recordi.getterminé){} terminé();` makes no sense, it equals:

```
while (!recordi.getterminé){

} 
terminé();
```

Regarding `onPostExecute`, yes, just write the function call in it:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

    // Anything here will be executed at the end, when doInBackground finishes
    terminé();
}
```

Comment: This is not possible : i have this error : cannot resolve method terminé() .. Thanks for your help

Comment: Right, that's because they belong to different classes. Check out the [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42319105/7373404) to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

use Broadcast/Receiver pattern, onhandleintent() will run on UI thread where you can make your buttons visible.
1.Start the async task .
2.Define a BroadcastReceiver, instantiate one in your activity and register/unregister it accordingly.
3.In onpostexecute() of async task just call sendBroadcast. You may need to pass a context parameter when instantiating the AsyncTask.
The onHandleIntent method of your app's broadcast receiver (the one you instantiated on step 2) will run on the UI thread, making all those UI updates safe.

Comment: tis was what i tried to use before posting on stackoverflow and it was not working ( the app keep crashing) for me but thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you use broadcast receiver? If so, please mention in the question.it's helpful for us to suggest you an answer.